# Java 7 SimpleDateformat misuse or issue?

Tags: java, parsing, date, format, simpledateformat

I'm using java 7 and I'm trying to parse a date from a flat file.

I this file's dates have the following format "30-Mar-2012 14:05:02". I can't change this, it depends on another software.

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#month) this format : "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" is the one to use.

But for unknown reason this is not working.

Here is a little program which reproduce the issue.

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date d = null;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat df;
            df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.FRANCE);
            d = df.parse("30-Mar-2012 14:05:02");

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        if (d != null) {
            System.out.println(d.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem does not happen when i put an "s" after "Mar" in the original date ("Mars" is the full name of March in French, this also work with "March" and Locale.US in the format).

Am-I doing something wrong ?
Is it really possible to do this that way ?
I there an undocumented issue in java about this ?

Comment: df.parse throws an exception

Comment: Is it giving problem for other months (short name) for French?

Comment: I could eventually extend DateFormat in a custom class. But i don't want to do this if SimpleDateFormat can do the job.

Comment: Unfortunately it is the same for every months

Comment: But I noticed an annoying thing. In french "Juin" and "Juillet" have the same short names "Jui".
Could it be the reason why java can't parse those dates ?

Comment: Would Joda Time be an option?

Comment: I think i've found a solution by using Locale.US but i can't send it for the moment...

Comment: Why are you parsing US formatted dates in French locale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation is here

```
    DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.FRENCH);
    for (String s : dfs.getShortMonths()) {
        System.out.print(s + " ");
    }
```

output

```
janv. f?vr. mars avr. mai juin juil. ao?t sept. oct. nov. d?c.
```

as you can see shortened form for mars = mars.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.
I already try this it's working (I edited my first message)
The problem is that i can't change the date format in my original files.

Comment: So I guess my date are not formated with the French local. I need to confirm that but i think I'll use Locale.US.

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Test your code

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(2012, 2, 30);

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat df;
        df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.FRANCE);
        String s=df.format(calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println(s);

        }
```

result prints : 30-mars-2012 23:17:46

So it's expecting `mars` instead of `Mar`

'Mar' is Locale.US

Comment: Yes its because French abbreviation are not corresponding to my input format. I'll use Locale.US Thanks for your answer.